# BLDC Commutation and output states of half bridges

Tags: analog, h-bridge, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am trying to run a BLDC motor using [TI DRV832](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8323.pdf).

In the datasheet, there is the following truth-table, where I do not know what are **GLx**, **GHx** and **SHx**. Also, what does **Hi-Z** do?

[image]

I want to control the bridge directly, so I assume the bridge is something like this:

[image]

I think I only need to set **GLx** and **GHx** into **H** and **L** states and no **Hi-Z** state is needed. Is this the correct assumption?

Comment: Pages 3 and 4 of the datasheet tell you what these are.

Comment: Without a highZ state, you won't be able to measure zero crossing voltage, and so commutate the motor properly without sensors. Are you intending to run sensored, or sensorless?

Comment: @Neil_UK My motor has HALL sensors, but I just want to use the hall sensor to check the position of the rotor at stop and then start with low RPM using HALL sensors and eventually switch to sensorless mode. Does this make any sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can't use sensorless without one winding highZ. Unless you run it like a stepper motor rather than a BLDC!

Comment: "I just want to use the hall sensor to check the position of the rotor at stop and then start with low RPM using HALL sensors and eventually switch to sensorless mode. Does this make any sense?" - not really. If you have sensors then why not use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume GLx, GHx and SHx probably mean something like "Gate Lowside 'x'", "Gate Highside 'x'" and "Source Highside 'x'" x just denotes transistor pairs/half-bridges 1,2,3.

The L or H state in the columns below GLx and HLx refer to the transistor being switched on or off (L=low/OFF,H=high/ON) or rather it is the state on the gate of the transistor, and in the SHx column it refers to the output of this half-bridge being high or low. the reason you see "high-Z" in the SHx column is because the output can be "high impedance", z=impedance, meaning that no current can flow into or out of the half-bridge, in contrast to the L or H states where the output is pulled fully to GND (L) or Vcc/supply (H). This happens when both the high-side and the low-side transistor of the half-bridge are turned OFF